# detect event on IE from visio

Tags: vba, visio

Can i have a link between a button on an IE page and a visio event ? ( for example : changing the color of a shape just by a click on a button on the IE page)

Comment: You'll need to add a little more detail.  For example, are you opening the IE instance from Visio?

Comment: Yes, I select a shape and I run my macro that opens an IE instance where I put some info and I insert them in my database based on the ID of my selected shape. Now when I press the button to record in my database ( in IE instance ), I would detect this event from visio to change the color of this shape

Answer (score 1):

Not really very easy unless you have access to the HTML content in IE as well, but you could use a VBA class which implements a "withevents" private variable to capture a reference to a particular element on the page, and which has an event handler to respond to browser-based events.  Eg. in a class "clsHTML":

```
Private WithEvents el As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Public Sub SetElement(t As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement)
    Set el = t
End Sub

Private Function el_onchange() As Boolean
    Debug.Print "captured change: value = " & el.Value
End Function
```

In other code, create an instance of the class and call "SetElement" using a reference to an element on the page in IE:

```
Dim objHTML As clsHTML  'global variable


Sub TestEvents()
   Dim IE As Object

    'set up your IE reference....

  Set objHTML = New clsHTML
  objHTML.SetElement IE.document.getElementById("tester2")
  Debug.Print "set capture"
End Sub
```

In this instance you're capturing the "change" event on a textbox, but other elements will expose different events....

Edit: I tested this in Excel, but I'm assuming something similar will also work in Visio.

Edit2: you would probably be much better off creating a form in Visio to handle this than sticking with automating IE.

Answer (score 0):

yes you should check the get started documentation of jquery

html :

```
<button id="mybutton" />
<div id="myshape">blabla</div>
```

javascript :

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $('#myshape').css('background-color', '#555555');
});
```