# How to sending JavaScript results from local file to VBA Webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-access

I'm using the standard webbrowser control in MS Access. The control shows a local HTML file. Now, I want to send data from HTML to VBA.

```
<input type="text" onchange="foo(this.value)">
```

How to send data to VBA? I have two problems:

1. If the HTML file is local, I found no solution to start JavaScript at all. If the file has an http URI, `alert()` for example is possible, but not if the file is local. How can I use JavaScript in a local file?
2. How can I send the result of a JavaScript function to VBA?

PS.: I'm not searching how to start Javascript from VBA (Webbrowser.Document.parentwindow.execscript)

Thx

Martin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388391/detect-event-on-ie-from-visio/7410092#7410092

Answer (score 2):

You can set up js-to-VBA communication using simple classes implementing WithEvents to hook up VBA references to elements in your hosted HTML page.

When the example below is run, editing and then clicking out of the HTML textbox (so firing the `onchange` event) will trigger a VBA messagebox via the class field linked to the input.

To find out how to fix your issues with local pages and js, Google "mark of the web".

In class module `clsHtmlText`:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents txt As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Public Sub SetText(el)
    Set txt = el
End Sub

Private Function txt_onchange() As Boolean
    MsgBox "changed: " & txt.value
End Function
```

In a UserForm with an embedded browser control `wb1`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim o As clsHtmlText '<< instance of our "withEvents" class

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim el As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    With Me.wb1
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        WaitFor wb1
        .Document.Open "text/html"
        'or you can load a page from a URL/file
        'Note: local pages need "mark of the web" in the markup
        .Document.write "<html><input type='text' size=10 id='txtHere'></html>"
        .Document.Close
        WaitFor wb1

        Set el = .Document.getelementbyId("txtHere")

        Set o = New clsHtmlText
        o.SetText el '<< assign the textbox so we can monitor for change events

    End With

End Sub

'utility sub to ensure page is loaded and ready
Sub WaitFor(IE)
    Do While IE.ReadyState < 4 Or IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```