Is it possible (in Microsoft Access) to attach a VBA event handler to an HTML event of a WebBrowser Control
I have an Access Form with a WebBrowser Control (b). I "write" b's content on the fly by:
    Dim h as String

    h = "<html><body>"
    h = h & "<form id='bf' ...>"
    h = h & "<input type='text' id='test' name='test'>"
    h = h & "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
    h = h & "</form>"
    h = h & "</body></html>"
    Call Me.b.Object.Document.Write(h)

I want to process the user's response (to "Submit") by a VBA function.
In my VBA code, the HTML Form bf can be accessed through Me.b.Object.Document.getElementById("bf"), that is an MSHTML.HtmlFormElement and exposes an attachEvent method with two araguments:
Function attachEvent(event As String, pdisp As object) As Boolean

How should I create a pdisp Object to complete the following?
    Call Me.b.Object.Document.getElementById("f").attachEvent("onsubmit", *???*)

Thanks in advance for any insight on this or any alternate solution to my problem.
Providing a "function pointer" with Address Of doesn't wotk. I presume that the Object required should be an instance of some WithEvents Class implmenting some interface... But Couldn't find any documentation on the subject.
Despite .Net, VBA MSHTML Library doesn't provide access to ObjectForScripting...

You can use a simple VBA class and WithEvents to trap events occurring on HTML elements in the web browser control.   See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43988381/478884

Example of using a class with WithEvents:
Class module clsHtmlInput:
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_btn As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Private m_txt As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Public Sub SetInputs(theButton, theTextBox)
    Set m_btn = theButton
    Set m_txt = theTextBox
End Sub

Private Function m_btn_onclick() As Boolean
    MsgBox "Clicked: " & m_txt.Value
End Function

Your userform:
Dim eventHandler As clsHtmlInput '<< instance of your "withEvents" class

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim el As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement, h As String
    With Me.wb1
        .navigate "about:blank"
        WaitFor wb1
        .document.Open "text/html"
        h = "<html><body>"
        h = h & "<input type='text' id='test' name='test'>"
        h = h & "<input type='submit' value='Submit' id='btnSubmit'>"
        h = h & "</body></html>"
        .document.Write h
        .document.Close
        WaitFor wb1

        Set eventHandler = New clsHtmlInput
        eventHandler.SetInputs .document.getElementById("btnSubmit"), _
                                .document.getElementById("test")

    End With

End Sub

'utility sub to ensure page is loaded and ready
Sub WaitFor(IE)
    Do While IE.readyState < 4 Or IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

If you're familiar with HTML and javascripting (or at least, the subset of "modern" HTML/js which is still supported in the older web browser control...), this can be a way to create interfaces which go beyond the basic VBA form controls.

Nice. Voted it up...

Thanks for the clear explanation of the exact solution to my problem. Indeed the very goal is to overcome limitations of VBA Forms, especially when, depending on the data, a dynamic structure of controls is needed. Thanks again!
