# Excel respond to a web DOM event via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to respond to a button click on a website opened via Excel VBA.

The code below is trying to getting it working as a test with Duckduckgo.

The web page loads fine but I just cannot seem to get the onclick event, which I need to do to grab the values out of the text input elements that the user will have filled in.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents IEButton As MSHTML.HTMLInputButtonElement

Public Sub Init(aButton As MSHTML.HTMLInputButtonElement)
    Set IEButton = aButton
End Sub

Private Function IEButton_onclick() As Boolean
    Debug.Print "Clicked"
    MsgBox "HI"
End Function
```

```vb
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim link As String
    link = "http://www.duckduckgo.com/"


    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate link
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set html = .document

        Dim ieBut As New clsIEButton

       ieBut.Init html.querySelector("#search_button_homepage")


    End With


ShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The web page loads fine but I just cannot seem to get the onclick
>   event, which I need to do to grab the values out of the text input
>   elements that the user will have filled in.

Please refer to the following sample code:

```
Private ieBut As clsIEButton 'global variable.
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim link As String
    link = "http://www.duckduckgo.com/"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate link
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set html = .document
        Set ieBut = New clsIEButton

        'transfer the button element and the html document.
        ieBut.Init html.getElementById("search_button_homepage"), html

    End With

End Sub
```

clsIEButton (class module)

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents IEButton As MSHTML.HTMLInputButtonElement
Private html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument



Private Function IEButton_onclick() As Boolean
    Debug.Print "button: clicked!"
    'based on the html document to get the entered value.
    Debug.Print html.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").Value

End Function


Public Sub Init(aButton As MSHTML.HTMLInputButtonElement, ahtml As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
    Set IEButton = aButton
    Set html = ahtml
End Sub
```

After entering the value and click the search button, the VBA output looks as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As soon as `cmdTest_Click` completes, all its local variables are destroyed, including `ieBut`. 
If you need that to hang around until someone clicks the button, you need to move

```
Dim ieBut As New clsIEButton
```

to the top of the module, outside of any Sub/Function.

Similar code here: [detect event on IE from visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388391/detect-event-on-ie-from-visio/7410092#7410092)

Comment: Great, I'm progressing, finally! Now, I get an error 462 "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" from line "    Set IEButton = aButton" in the class. Can you help with that?

Comment: Also, it seems to over ride the default behavior, is there a way to stop over riding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this part

```
    Set html = .document
    html.queryselector("#search_form_input_homepage").Value = "Excel VBA"
    html.queryselector("#search_button_homepage").Click
```

Put the following line before the action of the Cick

```
Range("A1").value = html.queryselector("#search_form_input_homepage").Value
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I want is to know when the button was clicked so I can check the value the user typed into the text input.

Comment: How will the user use the code.? Will he type the value in the text input using InputBox?

Comment: The user will click a button on the excel document which will load the web page, the user will complete the web form on the web page and click a submit button. That will send a POST reqest to a 3rd party but I want also capture the values the user entered and populate some cells within Excel.